# increase variables by alternating value in while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

```
i=297 
z=301
while [ $i -le 300 ] && [ $z -ge 301 ]
                    do 
findPeaks ~/ChIP-Seq/ExamChIP-Seq/TagDir/SRR1524"$i".fastq.gz.sam 
-style factor -center -o ~/ChIP-Seq/ExamChIP-Seq/PeaksFound/SRR1524"$i"_SRR1524"$z"peaks.txt 
-i ~/ChIP-Seq/ExamChIP-Seq/TagDir/SRR1524"$z".fastq.gz.sam
i=$(( $i +1))
echo "Peaks found for SRR1524$i with SRR1524$z"
                    done
```

I want $z to increase every 4 cycles while increases $i every cycle of the loop without skipping any values for $z

Comment: hm.. between 297 and 300 arent so much 4-cycles. :)

Comment: I actually need it to cycle $i from 297-300 while $z is 301 then after those 4 cycles put $i back to 297 and increase $z to 302 and then do that again when $z is 303

Comment: You'll need a nested loop for that: the outer one on ```$z``` and the inner one on ```$i```